# How ot Fix Out of Memory error in Matlab for 10800x10800 matrix?

Tags: windows, matlab, out-of-memory

Situation: How to deal with "out of
memory" error.

Basically the problem is I use 10800x10800 matrix. I am on 32-bit windows system.
I get out of memory error when I do this:

```
a=zeros(10800,10800);
```

This is what I get for memory:

```
>> memory
Maximum possible array:    393 MB (4.120e+08 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:   1097 MB (1.150e+09 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:    639 MB (6.697e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):    895 MB (9.387e+08 bytes)

*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.
```

System: Windows 32 bit

Comment: Do you even have enough memory? 10800x10800 is kinda big.

Comment: what's the `format` you are using?

Comment: What do you want to do with this large matrix?

Comment: Have you considered using `sparse` matrix?

Comment: Your matrix is `933 MB`! this should lead you to a self-explaining question!

Comment: @fpe: actually its: `10800*10800*8/2^20 = 889.89 MB` (of contiguous memory that is). Use `m = memory; m.MaxPossibleArrayBytes / 2^20` to see how big a matrix you can allocate

Comment: People seem to be assuming that your matrix will remain mostly zeros; is this true? For that matter what will you be using your matrix for?

Comment: Also there are all sorts of undocumented tricks to see the effect of memory fragmentation. Try: `feature memstats` or even `feature dumpmem`

Comment: I guess it's more matter of pre-allocation!

Comment: Also on 32-bit windows, there is a [3GB switch](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4M4ZNT/index.html) that adds an additional 1GB to the limit of 2GB of addressable memory per process.

Comment: I edited my original post guys, please check it. Obviously my array size is bigger than the limits set by Matlab. How do I increase those?

Comment: By the way, the matrix later gets filled with non-zero values, so sparse matrix is not the solution.

Comment: well there you have, you have more data than your memory allows. So the only question is do you need it available in memory all at once? If not, break it into into sub-matrices an work on each separately, clearing the old data you no longer need. Otherwise move to 64bit machine and buy more RAM :)

Comment: Possible related http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388

Answer (score 5):

Matrices are stored in a contiguous memory block. Allocation of such blocks may be problematic  when dealing with very large matrices (simply because a sufficiently large free block of memory may not be found).

Since you didn't provide any details about your code, I can only suggest ways to circumvent this problem:

1. If your matrix contains a lot of zeros, represent it as a [sparse matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html). It uses less memory for storing such a matrix by not storing the zeros.
2. Break down your matrix into smaller blocks, and modify your algorithm accordingly.
3. Use more efficient data types instead of double precision, if they can accomodate the range of values you're working with (credit to Amro and Rody for this suggestion). Consider using [single precision](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html) or [integer data types](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html) (and pay attention to unsigned integers as well!).

Comment: 3) use `single` instead of `double` if possible. This will cutdown the memory required by half (as in: `zeros([10800,10800],'single')`)

Comment: @Amro: Or of course even smaller types when possible (`logical`, `int8`, ...). Depends on the OP's actual problem of course

Comment: I edited my original post guys, please check it. Obviously my array size is bigger than the limits set by Matlab. How do I increase those?

Comment: @user2225930 Your edit is irrelevant to the solutions that others already gave you. Your options are, migrate to 64bit OS + buy more RAM, rewrite code to use block processing, use smart data types. Sparse arrays are usually convenient when you roughly have less than half of the array filled.

Comment: I am trying here to vectorise big matrices http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388 and particularly here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422409/how-to-use-parallel-vector-imagesc-with-less-memory-than-matrix

Answer (score 2):

If there is a significant portion of the matrix that will remain zero, use a [Sparse matrix](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)

```
S = sparse(10800, 10800)
```

If that isn't the case (matrices are dense) you have these options:

- Solve the problem in parts, using several smaller matrices.
- Use a computer with lots of memory and [Matlab 64bit](http://www.mathworks.se/support/solutions/en/data/1-YVO5H/) to use large dense matrices.

Comment: It is not sparse matrix, it gets filled later with non-zero values.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, can I modify how much memory Matlab is using? I mean, can I increase those limits?

Comment: See here http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html